# How manage multiple accounts in Twitter4J?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

How manage **multiple** accounts in **Twitter4J**? Someone have a code example?

Is necessary create one "application" for each account? or have a more pratical way?

Thanks,
Celso

Answer (score 4):

For managin multiple accounts u only need to create a instance of the Twitter class for each account you have the token and the token_secret, and you don't need to create a new application for each account you want to manage, just made the OAuth flow and take the token.